# What is the computational class of a reduced Wang B-machine?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, automata, computation-models, turing-completeness

A [Wang B-machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_B-machine) is Turing-complete and has only 4 instructions:

- `right`: Move head right.
- `left`: Move head left.
- `mark`: Mark square under head.
- `branch n`: If square under head is marked, jump to instruction $n$.

Inspired by [P′′](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2), consider a machine with the following instructions:

- `right`: Move head right.
- `markleft`: Mark square under head, then move head left.
- `branch n`: If square under head is marked, jump to instruction $n$.

Note that `mark = markleft; right`. What is the [computational class](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Computational_class) of this machine?

Comment: I highly doubt it. Because you can't move left without destroying its contents (marking everything), effectively the tape has become read-once memory. Since the only other information (the instruction pointer) is finite, I believe you become limited to something similar to a pushdown automata.

Comment: @orlp I edited the question to ask for the computational class.